# Populating a listview form with files and thumbnails

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create an addin for powerpoint that lets the user select a directory in a dropdown and then gets the list of powerpoint slides with thumbnails displayed in a listview form. The user should then be able to select the thumbnail and add the slides to the current presentation he/she is working on. (something like a personal slide library access directly from power point).

I have the general code for filling the listbox. But get a TypeError which i don't know how to fix.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s As String
    Dim folderspec As String

    folderspec = "U:\PowerPointFiles\"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.SubFolders

    ComboBox1.Clear

    For Each f1 In fc
        ComboBox1.AddItem f1.Name

    Next f1

    'ComboBox1.Activate    --> doesnt' work

    'Application.SendKeys "^{F4}" --> doesnt' work

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim fs, f, f1, MyFiles, s As String
    Dim MyFolder As String

    MyFolder = "U:\Methoden\power point trials\Addin Projekte\Slide Library Addin\" & ComboBox1

    MyFiles = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.pptx")

    ListView1.ListItems.Clear

    Do While MyFiles <> ""

        ListView1.ListItems.Add (MyFiles)  --> Type mismatch
        MyFiles = Dir

    Loop


End Sub
```

The result should be the list of .ppt files in the ListView including links.
From this I need to create the code to add the thumbnails.

Comment: What's the exact text of the error message and on what line does it occur?

Comment: ListView1.ListItems.Add (MyFiles)  --> Type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ... missed the fact that you'd already marked the problem line of code.

I've commented out a few lines of your original code and added slight changes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' You don't use all these variables, so no need to dim them here
'    Dim fs, f, f1, MyFiles, s As String
Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim MyFolder As String

    'MyFolder = "U:\Methoden\power point trials\Addin Projekte\Slide Library Addin\" & ComboBox1
' Substituted a folder that exists on my system and changed the filespec
' form *.PPTX to *.* to ensure some results at my end while testing.
MyFolder = "C:\Temp"

    MyFiles = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")

'    ListView1.ListItems.Clear
ListBox1.Clear
    Do While MyFiles <> ""

        'ListView1.ListItems.Add (MyFiles) '--> Type mismatch
ListBox1.AddItem (MyFiles)
        MyFiles = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand that i need to use a ListView instead of a ListBox inorder to add the thumbnaisl later. Can you adapt the code to use a ListView instead of a ListBox form? This is where i get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim strLoad As String
Dim lvwItem As ListItem
Dim MyFolder As String

ListView1.ListItems.Clear

MyFolder = "U:\Methoden\power point trials\Addin Projekte\Slide Library Addin\" & ComboBox1
strLoad = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.*")

Do While strLoad > vbNullString

   Set lvwItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , strLoad)

   strLoad = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg: Any Idea how I can display thumbnails in this listview ?

Comment: Not something I've had to do, but I'd probably start with this:  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/258942-can-i-put-pics-list-boxes.html